# This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

How can somebody post an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23363317) when the question is closed (marked as duplicate)?

I see a question marked as duplicate `8 mins ago` and someone posted an answer `5 min ago`.

This means the answer was posted 3 minutes after the question was closed.

Comment: I think there are 5 minutes window where you can post answers.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

We give people a server side grace period to answer questions, even if the question gets closed.

If the client side checks fail, for whatever reason, and someone does post an answer, we will accept it (for a while).

Also see:

[How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed)

Comment: It's unfortunate when people answer obvious duplicates

Comment: @dystroy - aye. Especially people who should know better.

Comment: What should we do in that specific case ? Should I post a question on meta ?

Comment: You can bring it up as an issue - It's been brought up before, but AFAIK, there is no real consensus on what the "right" thing to do is.

Comment: OK, [did it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261998/grace-period-for-answering-after-closing-obvious-duplicates)

Comment: @Oded Why was this grace period implemented? Is there any evidence that this is useful and doesn't cause more harm?

Comment: @Rizier123 - give people a chance to fix typos and quick edits without polluting the edit history. There is no evidence that it is harmful.

Comment: what does for a while means here?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ It seems to be around 4 hours if [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed) implementation is still in place

Comment: What is the reason for this (We give people a server side grace period to answer questions, even if the question gets closed.)?

Comment: @Don - so that they don't feel they have completely wasted their time writing and submitting an answer, only for it to be rejected.

Comment: Is it [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46618751/6910411) the same case, or is there something else going on here? 2 hours, looks like a pretty wide margin of error.

Comment: The window is about that wide, a few hours, @user6910411