# Grace period for answering after closing and obvious duplicates

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488597/using-a-string-as-an-object-member-name-in-javascript is a duplicate question that any JavaScript developer saw at least a few times.

I saw it and I closed it as duplicate. But another user, a few seconds later, due to the grace period, could write and submit an answer.

I find this situation sad. Why would we vote to close a question as a duplicate if some users can come later and provide useless answers, which will be seen in place of the canonical Q&A that we linked to?

How to deal with that?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/

Comment: Related?: [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/456814).

Comment: The answerer probably started writing before you hit the close button. Why should he need to discard his draft? It's probably not entirely useless (unless it's a bad, downvotable answer) because it deals with the question's specific problem.

Comment: Related?: [How was this answer posted after this question was closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/163250) and [Why was an answer allowed on a question that was merged into another one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79457/163250).

Comment: Why are you so worried about it, honestly?  It doesn't exactly hurt anything... it means Paul wasted a bit of his time probably, but what real harm was done?

Comment: On [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723698/why-abstract-class-is-better) the answer was posted 20 minutes after the Close. Seems a little long.

Answer (score 20):

You ask,

> Why would we vote to close a question as a duplicate if some users can come later and provide useless answers, which will be seen in place of the canonical Q&A that we linked to?

### There's Already a Sign That Says Where to Find Good Answers

At the top of every closed duplicate, you'll find this box,

[image: Screenshot]

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   <Link to canonical question> *N answers*

As you can see above, the duplicate clearly points to a ***canonical question*** with ***canonical answers***.

If users choose to ignore that sign and just use the answers on the non-canonical duplicate, **then that's *their* problem**, not ours, and I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: While this is true, perhaps some sort of indication that the original question is the "canonical" one would be useful? Seeing this, I merely think that the other is *a* duplicate; I don't think, "Oh, that's a canonical question with MUCH better answers!"

Comment: I don't think he is necessarily complaining about non-canonical answers more that why is there a grace period at all, which to me is the crux of the question. He may not realize that there is a slight race condition so SO allows the grace period. It seems SO has taken the approach to err on the side of the person answering so their answer doesn't go to waste. The software could reject answers but I think the prevailing thought is that it is better to encourage answers

Comment: @staticx Although that window is actually a 4 hour long window.  It's not like it's just a few minutes, and if they were prevented from posting the answer, they could still go and post the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Servy I think the windows was recently significantly shortened, actually, there should be a Meta post somewhere about it, let me look...

Comment: @Cupcake There have been requests to shorten it a number of times, but to my knowledge they've all been denied.

Answer (score 15):

You can do the same thing that you can do for any other unhelpful answer.  Downvote it.  That's what downvotes are for, answers that aren't helpful/useful.

Comment: Agreed. I'd just add that these answers _may be helpful to OP asking the question_ while _counter productive to the community_ - i.e. repeating and spreading the answers across multiple questions rather than of consolidating them to single canonical question that could be referenced later.

Comment: I don't think a correct answer deserves a downvote only because the answerer has not realized that the question was a duplicate.

Comment: Someone with that high of a rep *should* have known better and would see the close votes being cast (except for cases where it only takes 1 vote to close like mod or gold badge holder).

Comment: @vhu How is it helpful to the OP?  It's providing an answer that's of lower quality than the answers that are just one click away.

Comment: @Bergi Why?  The answer is unhelpful.  It is not a reflection on the post's author.  It's not necessarily even a statement that it's their fault.  It's simply a statement that the answer is not helpful, which it's not.

Comment: @Servy: But the answer *is* helpful to the question author? It comments on the specific problem, that there was only a minor syntactic issue, and provides the specific corrected code. Sure, cimmanon is right that an experienced user should have known better.

Comment: @Bergi If the answers in the duplicate don't answer the OP's question then they're not a duplicate.  If it's a duplicate then *by definition* the question is already answered.  Adding an additional lower quality answer is, by definition, not helpful.

Comment: @Servy It is perfectly possible for an answer to be more well suited to the specific question asker AND be a less valuable answer than the canonical answer to the community overall.  That's self evident, just like it's possible for (good) vanilla ice cream to be better than chocolate ice cream to me AND be less popular overall.  In any event, it's certainly possible for the answer to be a 'good' answer and not deserving of downvotes; there is not only one possible 'helpful' answer, and we don't generally downvote every single answer less helpful than the most helpful one.

Comment: @Joe So you want people to be going around posting lots of low quality answers to duplicate questions, helping help vampires while damaging the rest of the community?  You consider this beneficial behavior that should be encouraged?  Nothing you can ever possibly do is ever entirely devoid of benefits.  Every decision ever made by anyone has some conceivable benefits.  What matters is not the gross benefits but the net benefits.  The post is net harmful.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly harmful, no.  I don't think people are going to be posting 'lots' of these answers, nor that they're necessarily low quality - they are the same quality potential as any other answer.  I largely just don't understand the furor here.  Who's really hurt?

Comment: @Joe It hurts people that want to find quality content.  It hurts people that don't want to have their time wasted looking at low quality content.  It hurts people that have to spend their time cleaning it up.  It hurts people that end up reading the low quality answers in place of the high quality answers.  If the answer is actually of high quality and adds value not in the existing answers to the canonical question the the answer should be posted to the canonical question, not to the duplicate question.

Comment: People that want to find quality content will still get the duplicate warning highlighted up top.  Nobody has to spend time cleaning up - it's already cleaned up *by the duplicate closure*, which had to happen anyway.  Nobody has to read the answer on the dup, and probably not many will if the duplicate mark is clear enough.  Cupcake's answer below covers this well.

Comment: @Joe If nobody is ever going to read them then why do you want to keep them around?  If nobody is reading it then it's not helpful.  Of course, I reject the premise that nobody will ever read it.  Experienced users read lots of answers to evaluate their quality and evaluate them so that other less experienced readers will know whether the answer is worth reading.  The first few that determine that the post is not helpful should be indicating that so that future readers won't need to bother evaluating it.  That's how SO was designed; answers get vetted by the community.

Comment: @Servy, I meant that in general, though it doesn't seem to be applicable in this specific case.

Comment: Sometimes an answer to a "duplicate" question can be better than the answers on the original. Doesn't happen often, but it's possible. Blindly downvoting just because other answers exist is wrong spirited.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't say anything about blindly downvoting, I said you should downvote the answer if you feel that it's not helpful/useful.

Comment: @Servy it's strongly implied that the answer is automatically unhelpful, even if that's not what you said.

Comment: @MarkRansom The question specifically stated that he was referring to answers that he felt were "useless" and that weren't adding value.  Of course, even if the answer isn't terrible, it still belongs on the canonical question, not the duplicate, so the author should still be encouraged to post it in the appropriate place.

Comment: @Servy I've followed that advice twice in the last week, only to see my answers be totally ignored. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26092476/5987 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26070512/5987.

Comment: @MarkRansom So you're saying you want people to continue posting answers to duplicate questions and upvoting them because that gives you more rep than keeping answers to their canonical questions?  Looks like you need to get your priorities straight.

Comment: I'm not worried about rep, I have plenty. But my experience has been that new answers to old questions are almost completely invisible because they're at the bottom of a page that nobody's actively looking at. And that is completely tangential to the point I came here to make, which is - Don't punish people for leaving an answer! You don't have to reward them for it either, if that's your feeling.

Comment: @MarkRansom Answers to duplicate questions are *far* less visible than answers to more recent canonical questions.  The canonical questions are going to get far more visibility in general, and on top of that the whole point of the duplicate system is to point people to the canonical.  Late answers to canonical questions also can very much move up to the top place, they just need to actually be a better answer than what's there.  It happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The particular complaint on the answer itself - that it is preventing deletion - is misguided.  Duplicates aren't particularly desired to be deleted.  The reason we keep them around - answers or no - is that they help direct people to the right answers.  People might search with different terms, bring up the duplicate, and then get directed to the right answer, where the original answer didn't show up early on their search.  After all, a decent percentage of duplicates are likely people who didn't immediately find their answer in a search.

It's not like the duplicates are using up valuable computing resources or something; the reason we close them is so people don't bother answering them, but once they (quickly) fall off of the top of the question pages they're not hurting anyone by staying around, and sometimes help.

Comment: Only a tiny minority of duplicates end up being effective windows into canonical questions.  Yes, some of the duplicates that use radically different terminology can accomplish this, but *most* don't, because they *don't* have radically different terminology, nor any better google juice.  The roomba already takes this into account, not deleting duplicate questions that have a large number of views (i.e. redirects to the canonical question).  The few percent of duplicates that add value in this way will already be kept alive, there is no need to keep the rest of the trash.

Comment: The point is simply that there's no harm in keeping them.  You've already spent more effort arguing about this than it would save if this policy changed, after all...

Comment: Yes, there is harm in keeping them.  It encourages unhelpful behavior, which feeds itself creating continually more low quality content, drowning out the high quality content.  It encourages people to post questions without bothering to so much as search first, it encourages people to waste their time reading, answering, reviewing, and evaluating these questions.  And no, it's not inconsequential amounts of time.  This type of thing is happening hundreds of times a day.  That adds up fast.