# Rewarding overzealous users for answering duplicate questions is undermining the site

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, upvotes, gamification

When a user posts a question that is, perhaps unknown to them, a duplicate of a FAQ, the correct response is to close the question as a duplicate of the FAQ, with *no other answers* to the new question. The new question should serve only as a pointer to the FAQ. The new question is retained because although a duplicate, its different wording adds to the set of variations in the ways of asking essentially the same question, and so might assist later searchers. As I understand it, that has always been part of the design of SE; one of the things that makes it more than just another Q&A site.

(You disagree? Consider that a duplicate question is a kind of closed question, and a closed question may have no more answers. Closing as a duplicate must have the intention that duplicates should not have direct answers)

But that is not happening, at least for a popular tag I am interested in ([java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)), which has many newcomers. Instead, when a duplicate is posted a race begins. Old hands who are trying to curate the site sigh to themselves, find the original of the FAQ and vote to close as a duplicate. Meanwhile, newcomers who know a little more than the OP, as well as overzealous members, rush to answer the question. In many cases the latter win the race, and gain some up votes and one of them gets accepted as the answer.

Just today I saw yet another question that was a duplicate of "is Java pass by reference". I voted to close, but before I had even done that a user with a reputation over 100k had fired off an answer and got an upvote. When I returned to the question a few minutes later that answer had got two more upvotes.

The newcomers who answer the question know no better, and are not the focus of my question. The longer term users who answer these questions are who I want to talk about. They *must* know the question is a FAQ, so they must have made a conscious decision to answer the question rather than voting to close.

It seems to me they have been bought by the prospect of some easy up votes. This means the gamification rewards of the system are driving the site quality down, rather than contributing to the site.

**The gamification reward for answering a duplicate question must be reduced or eliminated.** That is, there should be a mechanism for indicating not only that a question should not have any more answers (closure) but should *never have received answers in the first place*. And when that happens the answers of the question should give no reputation for upvotes (which has been proposed before, but rejected on weak grounds IMHO), or reduced reputation for up votes (perhaps fairer to those who genuinely did not know the question is a duplicate).

I note that the site moderators can not be responsible for doing this, because of the volume of questions and because it requires knowledge of the subject the question is about. Another super power for gold tag holders, perhaps?

Comment: Of all the words in the English language there's got to be a better phrase than "rep whore" to describe this.

Comment: @Flexo Flagrant Gamification Victim?

Comment: @Flexo in Victorian English that might have been referred to as "players" rather than "gentlemen".

Comment: @Flexo [I've suggested "rep addict"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late#comment13292_252077) in the past, but unfortunately "rep whore" is an [official meme of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19522/163250).

Comment: Worth noting that some people don't believe in closing as duplicate, or believe in a strict interpretation of "_exact_ duplicate", or, slightly less strictly, believe that only the question as written, rather than the underlying problem or its solution are to be considered. In other words, not everyone's doing it for teh repz, although it's a problem regardless.

Comment: An "official" meme? My eyes are burning. The cultural weight of a phrase can ensure it takes a lot of effort to remove. It's certainly nothing to so with a single answer on MSE @cupcake. If you want people to stop using it you need to post something here and be eloquent.

Comment: @Ben I didn't mean to suggest that it has anything to do with a single answer, my point was that it's been [long ingrained and accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/253351/1) into the culture of Meta.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: You know, I think a lot of people out there would prefer to use "overzealous" to describe people who review and close questions...

Comment: How about just "high reputation users"? Low reputation users might  not know better; it's the 100k+, gold-badge ones answering obvious duplicates that really make *me* want to give up on looking for duplicates.

Comment: @Flexo You're right, *whore* is an incorrect metaphor since a whore's acts remain private whereas answering questions that shouldn't be answered is public littering for a reward. So… polluter? Advertiser? Spammer?

Comment: @BoltClock, true, that was only an attempt on my part, feel free to switch it for a more appropriate term if you have one :)

Comment: Something similar was discussed here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261998/grace-period-for-answering-after-closing-and-obvious-duplicates .

Comment: As I consider myself one of the "newcomers", let me ask this perhaps naive question: What harm is actually done by duplicate questions being answered?

Comment: @Flexo Better term for "**rep whore**" --> "**reprobate**", contains the term "**rep**" and is defined as "[**an unprincipled person**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reprobate)", which seems appropriate based on the behaviour they exhibit.

Comment: @fbitterlich If they are answered *well*, not much really. The problem is that newcomer questions rush-answered by newcomers are seldom more than short fix-my-immediate-issue answers which are either wrong, partly wrong, or simply don't explain the issue well enough to really help anyone long-term. (That's obviously a generalisation.) All the while there may be a duplicate with a great, long, in-depth answer sitting there which would actually spread real knowledge. Catch-a-fish vs. teach-to-fish...

Comment: @Tanner What if the principle is to *answer questions as best as possible*, or even just *as many as possible*? Maybe that's *misguided*, but hardly *unprincipled*.

Comment: @deceze rep-whore is hardly complimentary...

Comment: There is much potential for collateral damage. Answerers might genuinely not be able to find the duplicate. Or a question is much later closed as a duplicate of a newer one, because the newer one is better and has better answers.

Comment: @Tanner Absolutely, never said so either. I quite dislike the condescending "repwhore" term. It's making assumptions about the answerer's intentions, which are probably often wrong. SO's central point it to *ask and answer questions*. People do that. They get called names for it. WTF? Just as it may not be obvious for newbs how to ask a good question, not everyone is on the same boat with regards to how to answer them either.

Comment: So, maybe a better solution would be to somehow "merge" a question once it has been deemed a duplicate, so that anybody accessing the duplicate (and not bothering to follow the link to the original question) could somehow see the (possibly better and thus higher ranked) answers...?

Comment: Perhaps the power of Mjölnir could be extended to eliminating reputation gained by answering the duplicate? So no actual penalty, but no gain either, I feel this would nicely put the kibosh on gamification - hell, as a bit of a repwhore myself, it would certainly stop me in my tracks!

Comment: Look ma!  I've answered this question more than a dozen times, but I don't seem to be able to find the duplicate.  So I'll go ahead and answer it.  (Somehow my eyes never seem to find obvious duplicates in the list of "related questions" on the right.)

Comment: It sounds like the problem are not the answers, but users who intentionally don't vote to close.

Comment: @Chris Right. Now we just need to prove *intention*... :)

Comment: @gnat Yes, deletion of down-voted duplicates will help.

Comment: BTW: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265202/cant-get-question-answered-due-to-duplicate ← this user may or may not be "worthy of our attention", but he's a great example of how rigorously closing as dupe does not always actually help the people the system was supposed to help.

Comment: @Chris Amusingly, on a number of occasions the ones answering such posts are gold-badge holders in those tags who have the fscking _insta-close_ powers.  And guess what they use it for: for reopening the question arguing: "No ma!  It's not a dupe."  Many of them might not even be ashamed to attribute the Theory of Relativity to themselves.

Comment: @deceze Mistakes always happen, even if in that case it does not seem like a mistake to me. The goal has never been to help individual users. If it was, we should forget all the rules and just allow anything (making SO similar to all the places it wants to be different from).

Comment: @kapa No, it wasn't a mistake. But the OP's question obviously was *not* answered by it being closed as a dupe. Yes, it *should* have been, but no, the OP didn't get it. In this case, pointing to the dupe and also adding some custom phrasing so he knows how to apply it to his situation would have actually helped him. Just closing as dupe didn't. Which gets us back to... are we here to answer questions, from however many angles as needed, or not? I think calling everyone who doesn't "get it" names isn't going to do anything. Q.E.D.

Comment: @deceze I don't really see yet what your goal is with this. We are certainly not here ONLY to answer questions, otherwise we would be happy to do so in an old-school forum. We are not here to help everyone and hold their hands, and AFAIK this has never been the goal. Name-calling is not something I'm really interested in, it is a normal human thing, you cannot do anything about it. If they do not "get it", they try better or find a place that is built/paid to tutor them, taking their specific, PERSONAL needs into account. This is not that place.

Comment: @kapa That's pretty much my goal: question and clarify what exactly it is we want. I think we agree that what we want SO to be and what we currently perceive it to be are at odds with each other. To be realistic, we won't stop new users from asking new questions, and by necessity most of those new questions will be "bad" by our current definition of the term. Continuing to fret about this state is unproductive. Either we accept that it's the way it is and we roll with it and help people, or we do some drastic changes to stop the problem (new questions). I don't see another solution.

Comment: @deceze That is why I'm asking. In that case, we are on the same boat. We might have different ideas about which way to go, but that does not really matter now. A direction must be chosen, otherwise SO is doomed. But this decision is not ours to make, and I'm not sure whether the owners see things the way we do. I don't really see what could we do about this.

Comment: @kapa At the very least we can enjoy the ride and do what we came here to do. Not beat everyone up including ourselves over things we have no control over... :)

Comment: @deceze Emotional involvement would certainly be a bad idea :).

Comment: Closed as duplicate, hah.  Can we get the answers merged?

Comment: The irony of this entire post, both question and answers, is immense.

Comment: anyone who uses "rep wh---" is an antisocial fool, or 9 years old and totally unaware of what they're doing.  a good phrase is just **"rep-hound"**.  (@Tanner 's suggestion of "rep-robate" and other funny suggestions are just too subtle - rep-hound is straightforward)

Comment: fix the duplicate question problem first, then this problem will go away naturally

Answer (score 70):

There should be a rep bonus for being the first to identify the duplicate.

Duplicate questions don't get deleted because they are valuable as signposts, so the act of identifying the duplicates is a valuable contribution to the site.

A rep bonus will create an incentive for people to spend time finding duplicates. As an answerer I sometimes answer questions that I think probably would have a duplicate if I spent enough time looking for it, both because it's quicker and because there's no incentive to find the duplicate.

Also, as others have pointed out a suitably tailored answer tends to be more helpful for the OP anyway, so I'm not sure we should see it as a bad thing that a duplicate gets its own answers too.

A more sophisticated (i.e. more coding, less likely to get done even if it seems like the best solution) variant on a rep bonus for finding a duplicate would be to make "this is a duplicate" into an explicit kind of answer that competes for votes with the real answers, rather than actively closing the question. It could provide less rep per upvote to keep things balanced.

Comment: I like that last idea.

Comment: The idea of giving rep for finding duplicates isn't a bad one, but it also encourages closing questions that are almost duplicates but not quite, also deserving their own answers. By doing so, you're rewarding a behaviour that can potentially stand in the way of a good Q&A. (I'm not saying the idea is completely bad, just that it may have unintended consequences, some of which already exist with the current close as duplicate mechanism indeed.)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226016/reward-duplicate-closing-5-for-the-first-voter

Comment: It would still require others to agree with your VTC, so there's some counterbalance. But that's the rationale behind the "more sophisticated" variant, because it uses the voting mechanism to identify whether the characterisation as a duplicate is valid or not.

Comment: "*It would still require others to agree with your VTC*" Surely, the asker should have a say to agree whether or not that other question provides any answer to them. (Also partly a problem with the current system.)

Comment: Perhaps being able to take a link to an existing *answer* (not question) and posting it as an answer would work? The answer would appear just like regular answers, perhaps specially highlighted or such, maybe Twitter retweet style-ish. Upvotes on that answer would provide the original poster with the regular rep, and the dupe-finder with a little bit of rep.

Comment: @deceze, that's not a bad idea. Thinking about what I was saying in my answer, there is something very unsatisfactory with closing as dupe (not just for canonical questions in the end), in the end, in terms of useful knowledge, it's the same as writing an answer that says "Try this `http://.../dup`", which may be a bit helpful, but rarely provides an actual answer (there's a parallel between dupes and link-only answers in general...). Making advantage that the answer actually is within SO, as you suggest, would certainly be beneficial.

Comment: I'd +1 the rep bonus for finding duplicates, but strongly -1 the idea making duplicates into special answers. I suggest you split these up into two different answers, we do not really know now what people are voting on :).

Comment: Would the bonus also apply to those wielding the [dupe hammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/234299)?

Comment: @Bruno Disagree; giving rep for finding duplicates *is* a bad idea because it means people will just run around voting everything as duplicates to get rep.

Comment: @TylerH, so yes, essentially the downsides I mentioned in my comment effectively make it a bad idea indeed :-)

Comment: +1, the bonus should be big as well, so there's a bigger incentive than more or less copy pasting the answers of existing questions.

Comment: I think any action you do that improves SO deserves somekind of reward.  Currently, I would like to increase my rep, but that's kinda hard when most common stuff is answered already (earning rep for those users that were lucky enough to get those big answers in early).  So I have the option, answer or mark as duplicate.  One gets me rep, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 22):

Firstly, there's a mismatch between the advertised goals of SO (["*With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)) and the way it works "*Ask questions, get answers, no distractions*" with whole reputation mechanism is purely based on asking questions and writing answers, biased towards writing answers. (In addition "*every question about programming*" doesn't mention anything about duplicates.)

Reputation aside, many of us who provide answers just do it mostly because they're quite happy helping people and sharing what they know. (Other side effect: some questions can be intellectually challenging, and it's also a good exercise to practice explaining something to someone else.)

Very few duplicates are *exact* duplicates. There's often something slightly different in the context, or the way the question is asked. I tend to try to tailor my answers to each question, so that it matches the exact problem in the question. This gives the reader (OP or someone else) a better flow to understand the issues in general. Duplicates tend to break that. There was a time were answers to duplicates were moved semi-automatically to the duplicate target, but that's often unsatisfactory in practice: reading the original question and the answers to the duplicate didn't always completely make sense.

"*is Java pass by reference*" as a standalone question is a bit obvious, but was the full question an exact duplicate? (I suppose in such a simple case it can be.)
There are also often little details around that makes the whole Q&A more useful to anyone reading it more useful.

Name calling those who answer such questions just doesn't help. Most answerers do it to help, for free. Those who do it purely for the points are merely playing the game that's put in front of them. Of course, that's why you're suggesting altering those reward rules. The problem is that there's always going to be some grey area of questions that actually are not perfect matches and that someone will have spent time writing a possibly good answer for. That could clearly be unfair on those who spend time trying to help.

Another example, is that it's not always easy to find an exact duplicate. Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24553930/372643) I answered a few days ago. When I first read it, I thought there was no way it wasn't a duplicate, so I started to look for them. Yet, I couldn't find anything specifically about installing the JDK (as opposed to the JRE) (it also became clear that some of the elements in the comments were also relevant, and made it slightly different to what had been asked before). So, OK, I got 1 upvote out of this, but frankly, I don't care that much, considering the time I've been on SO and the rep I have, getting 10 points is good, but I don't get massively excited about it.

There is of course the notion of canonical questions. Those are a good idea in principle, but SO and its gaming system don't really work well for them.

- The "canonical" question might be a good idea in principle, but such a question often includes more notions than asked in the question, or at least presented sufficiently differently that the OP won't necessarily understand it. Closing a duplicate towards a canonical question is about as helpful as pointing to a blog in a link-only answer saying ("Try this: http://...").
- There's no real way of merging existing answers and rewarding the initial authors fairly. Sure, one can copy and paste elements of duplicate answers together into a canonical answer, but you then take the points when others have effectively done most of the research and writing for you. That's just not right, and even if you someone keep the link to credit the initial answers, the authorship trace becomes very tangled (not even sure that would be compatible with the licence). I know editing is encouraged on SO, but *editing* and *authoring* are different concepts that are presented in fundamentally different ways (this is why edits that change the answer substantially are discouraged).

I know duplicates can sometimes be annoying, but they're always easier to identify as such when you already know what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: Very eloquently stated what I've been trying to piece together over several iterations... See, dupes are good. ;)

Comment: @deceze, yes, I wonder how Meta users are going to vote on this almost "duplicate answer" (of course, not an *exact* one) ;-)

Comment: @deceze, ah yes, downvotes are coming, I was expecting no less.

Comment: This aside, I've seen stuff about "SO being negative" lately and all that. Some seem to blame it on the poor quality of questions (which may well be true), but from an answerer's point of view, what would make me reduce my activity here is the will to close that seems to have increased.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. Old timers complain about the influx of new content and how to fight against it, newcomers complain about the fighting back. Neither side wins. As I see it, unless SO closes down, this dynamic is not going to change. We should start to learn to live with this situation instead of continually trying to invent new ways to stop it.

Comment: @deceze, I admit bad questions can irritate me too, but there are a questions not too badly written by people who genuinely don't know. One closing behaviour that annoys me is for answerable questions that are [borderline in terms of subject](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262787/372643) (i.e. more sysadmin-oriented, but still very relevant for a software developer). Sure we don't all have to agree, but I can ignore questions on say "php" or "javascript", why can't others learn to ignore questions that are very important to fellow developers, but just not them directly (e.g. on "htaccess").

Comment: "Very few duplicates are exact duplicates" irrelevant to my question, as I am talking about questions that the community *already accepts* are duplicates and have been closed as duplicates.

Comment: "Another example, is that it's not always easy to find an exact duplicate" irrelevant, as my post is about experienced members who must be aware of the numerous previous duplicates, and would know the appropriate search terms to use.

Comment: "but SO and its gaming system don't really work well for [canonical questions]" perhaps true, but tangental to my question.

Comment: @Raedwald It appears to me you are basing all this on the following premise: 1. Everything that's even remotely answerable by a dupe must be closed as a dupe. 2. People who *should* know this and aren't doing it must be punished because repwhoring. - To which I say: 1. Maybe the dupe doesn't actually help the OP, maybe he needs it answered in another way. Good developers see similarity patterns, newbs don't. 2. There are more diverse reasons for deciding to not close as dupe, possibly because 1.

Comment: @Raedwald ... The point being, what's your *goal*? Work for the system for the system's sake? Or help people that have questions? Undoubtedly these cases you speak of exist and should absolutely be closed. And there *are* bad questions that should be closed. I just don't see it as such a widespread problem that we have to codify any of that as part of how SO works. Just use your judgement within the existing system.

Comment: "Everything that's even remotely answerable by a dupe must be closed as a dupe" no. In fact, if you look around Java questions you will see that I (and others) add cross links to similar, but not duplicate, questions using comments.

Comment: @Raedwald, about "*questions that the community already accepts are duplicates*". (A) Of course you're implicitly talking about questions that are to be closed as duplicates, even if they're not yet, since you're talking about the consequences of closing as duplicate. (B) What "the community" accept as duplicates often reflects what just 5 voters, who may just have been beaten into submission just before getting enough rep to vote, have voted to close as duplicate. Remember that once a dup vote is made, it enters the queue where people might not have sufficient knowledge to make an assessment.

Answer (score 8):

Proposal: Add "re-answering" as a feature. [@GaneshSittampalam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265221/476) shall be credited with the idea, just posting it separately to be able to get separate feedback on it and expand on it.

- users can take the link to an existing *answer* and re-post it as answer
- the answer will appear in the list of regular answers to the question, specially marked so it's clear that it's a repurposed answer (think Twitter's retweet feature)
- the answer can be upvoted as usual, which will give the regular rep to the original poster, and a little bit of rep to the user who posted it as dupe
- the answer can be downvoted, but this will not affect the original poster's rep (because the answer may simply be out of place in the new question, due to no fault of the original poster); the user who posted it as dupe loses some rep
- comments can be left on the answer as if it was a regular answer in this question
- optionally: once the answer is accepted, the question is closed as duplicate

This would (hopefully) encourage users to find existing answers instead of inadequately recreating answers, while at the same time allowing some tailoring of the existing answer to the OP's particular situation through comments.

Comment: In case of too many downvotes: It was all @GaneshSittampalam's idea! ;)

Comment: I personally like this idea.

Comment: I like the idea, but if there is no penalty to down-votes on a *re-answered* question then there is a also possibility of abuse as someone can just keep *re-answering* a question to anything that seems even remotely related.

Comment: @Jack *"the user who posted it as dupe loses some rep"*

Comment: Ah OK, somehow I didn't see that part.

Comment: FWIW I think this is a different proposal to mine, which was just about posting duplicate *questions* as answers. Posting the specific answers makes much more sense.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199050/217863

Answer (score 8):

Changing the rep might make you feel happier about the problem, but won't solve it.

I occasionally answer questions that end up marked as dupes. I could not care less about reputation at this point, I am not playing the game in that way. I do it because if I know the answer to the question then I'm typically more interested in providing it than I am in curating the site. So if I can't find a dupe quickly myself then I stop looking, and sometimes it doesn't even occur to me to search for dupes before answering (aside from anything else it's really boring, and if SO is boring I stop). Taking away the rep *will not change my behaviour*.

Very occasionally I even answer questions that already have a vote as a dupe, either because I disagree with it or because I don't think the answers to the dupe answer the new question well. For example, it's not all that uncommon for a valid question with a very simple answer to be a subset of a separate valid question. Then yes, OK, the accepted answer to the big question does indeed answer this question, somewhere in the middle of paragraph 13. I hope nobody is out with pitchforks desperate to prevent this kind of dupes having their own more specialized answers (as well as being closed as dupes). I think the people providing those specialized answers should get rep for it. They're just as valuable to future visitors with the same specific problem, as the general answer is to future visitors with the general problem.

What's needed is tools for the people who want to curate, to make the site be as it should be. In this case I suppose what should happen is an easy means to move one or more of the answers on a dupe over to the original (didn't this used to be called "merging"?). The new answers may *or may not* merely repeat the old answers exactly, so I would ask those concerned about this problem to lobby for the tools to let them make a sound judgement on this, rather than applying the same rule to all.

Of course not all such answers should be moved. Some because they just repeat the old answers, but also some because they don't properly answer the old question. Unless, of course, the use of the "dupe" close reason is really tightened up to not just mean that the old answers answer this question, but *also* that any good answer to the new question would answer the old question. That change wouldn't help IMO, in fact it would result in a lot more near-dupes with their own answers. So to me, the solution is to selectively migrate novel answers to the old question, and retain answers that specifically deal with this new version of the question.

Comment: Agreed. The main problem with merging is that it may sometimes require more than just a little bit of editing, the presentation model of SO doesn't really allow for multiple authorship. OK, we're encouraged to edit others' answers to fix little thing, but there's a point where it's more than editing, and there's no mechanism to acknowledge each author properly in this case, unfortunately. SO was never built like Wikipedia.

Comment: @Bruno: yes, my proposed new feature would have to be lighter than a merge. Basically the new answers are moved if they answer the old question, but the questions aren't changed at all (other than the new one gaining the "this is a dupe of X" banner ofc). Then people could gain significant rep from answering "subset dupes", not so much from answering "precise dupes" since their answer soon gets dropped into the existing pool of answers that already has an accepted good answer.

Comment: "Changing the rep might make you feel happier about the problem, but won't solve it." this is not about rep jealously. This is about the gamification rewards of teh system rewarding the wrong kinfd of behaviour.

Comment: @Raedwald: are you saying that (for the purposes of this question) you're not interested in reducing the number of such answers? Your goal is simply that they not be rewarded with rep?

Comment: @SteveJessop Errr... no, I want to reduce useless duplicate answers by removing or reducing the gamifaction rewards for them.

Comment: Well, then changing the rep might make you feel happier about the problem (because you think the answerers are driven by gamification rewards so you think they'll improve). But my best estimate is that it won't help (because I don't think the "longer term users" to whom you restricted your question, are really in it for the rep). Aside from the occasional addict, rep is for herding new users.

Comment: That said, if you're keen on the gamification aspect then you could just downvote. It's a different axis of reward, but I'd guess that almost all long-term users are (in pure rep terms) disproportionately averse to downvotes. I'd pay far more attention to improving (or deleting) an answer that got one upvote and five down, than I would to one that got no votes at all, even though the rep is the same.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>"Repwhores"</strike> "overzealous users" is making assumptions about the user's intentions, which are probably often wrong. SO's central point is to *ask and answer questions*. People do that. They get called names for it. WTF?

Yes, some may do it for the shiny unicorn points. But really, if that's your primary goal in life, you have bigger problems. I suppose there are *some* people who are high on getting rewards, but I don't think that's the majority of users or that this state lasts very long. My theory, and I know this is *way* out there, is that people simply like answering questions. Shocker, I know.

Just as we a fighting to educate new question *askers* about how to ask good questions, we need to educate *answerers* that answering a question is not actually always the best course of action.

The way I see it, there are pretty much three stages to both sides:

**Askers**

- newb: asks terrible questions when he should be using Google instead
- experienced: asks good questions, to the point, answerable, generalised
- guru: hardly asks questions anymore, since he has figured out how to fix his own problems

**Answerers**

- newb: OMG, programming is so cool, check out this awesome copy and paste code I found, it'll totally fix your issue
- experienced: posts good, well thought out answers, spreads good knowledge
- guru: knows when *not* to answer a question

Instead of punishing users for doing what they're asked to (answer questions) and calling them names, we need to raise awareness of duplicates and why it's better to close questions sometimes. Not everyone is hanging around SO all the time and has seen all the duplicates a million times; not everyone has the same philosophy of SO for that matter.

IMO, as long as an answer isn't outright *wrong*, there's no reason to punish the user who posted it. If it's a *good* answer, it deserves upvotes regardless of whether somebody else has already posted a similar good answer before elsewhere on the site. There are a million different reasons for why that user might have posted that duplicate answer instead of close voting (couldn't find good dupe, didn't think dupe was quite on target, doesn't know about dupes, just really felt like answering that particular question, etc.). Don't punish a user that takes good actions (posts a good answer), just because he could have taken an *even better* action.

Reputation is lost again when duplicates are closed and deleted, so there's no longterm gain for "overzealous users" as long as *someone* closes the question and it gets deleted.

---

Trying to summarise my point from the below comments:

- SO has two conflicting goals:

  1. get as much content and contributions as possible
  2. cut down on the number of contributions to keep quality up
- SO promotes two conflicting behaviours:

  1. write and contribute as much as possible (to gain points)
  2. stop people from contributing too much (works against gamification)
- <strike>"repwhore"</strike> "overzealous" needlessly attributes maliciousness
- you can't prove "intent"; did the user post the answer because he wants rep, or did he want to contribute, which SO encourages
- don't punish/not reward users for unwritten rules and/or conflicting promoted goals

The only answer I see in this system is to reward closing as dupe, possibly even more so than writing a new answer. That will have its own problem of probably leading to a lot of bogus, easy, incorrect close votes though. You can hardly win in this either way, at least don't punish people while there's no clear statement on how they *should* behave.

One last consideration: IMO it's not even *bad* to have duplicated content, as long as that content is all *good*. Different people answer the same issue from different angles using different terms. They can all be *correct*, but some are more understandable to certain people than others. An answer written for an extremely experienced programmer may be useless for a novice, because it sounds like gibberish. Having the same content expressed in "newbie terms" elsewhere adds value, even if it's technically a dupe.

I agree that it's terrifically *annoying* for regulars to see the same old, same old questions and answers again and again and it just makes you roll your eyes all day long. However, that's because you're a *regular*. Not everyone feels that same annoyance. Not everyone has seen it a million times. Not everyone gets tired of answering the same question over and over. Not everyone has progressed to seeing SO as the internet's canonical knowledge base instead of *the site I like to go to learn and maybe answer a few things I know.*

Comment: SO isn't just about asking and answering questions, it's about `working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming`. I'd argue that duplciate questions and answers reduce the quality of that library.

Comment: Re: your edit, we do not want duplicates to be deleted, as they provide more paths to the correct answer(s). Therefore, our overzealous friends get to keep the rep they earn by posting the same answer over and over again. The suggestion to neuter that rep does not strike me as *punishment* -- after all, answerers will not actually *lose* reputation in the process.

Comment: @Rawling Agreed. However, that is an implicit goal only apparent to experienced users who know the meta-philosophy behind SO. On the face of it SO is encouraging users to *ask and answer questions*.

Comment: @Frédéric If someone takes the time to post an actual good answer, being blissfully ignorant about existing dupes for whatever reason, and doesn't get the promised reward, that's punishment IMO. *Everyone gets rep, __except you__.*

Comment: Hardly implicit - that quote comes from the first paragraph of the [SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Comment: @Rawling Nowhere is anyone introduced to the idea of *canonical answers* and closing as duplicate though. SO is not really sending a clear message that we want every question only once at all. Understandably so, because those are two opposing goals. SO wants more and more questions to keep the site alive, but they don't want certain types of questions. The contradiction here is what's causing this issue we're debating.

Comment: @deceze, that's... not really the case we're discussing here I'm afraid. High-rep answerers can hardly be blissfully ignorant about dupes: they can see the close votes piling on (which they often race against), and they most probably remember the last time they answered the same question.

Comment: @Frédéric Sure. But again, don't assume that user does it because of "repwhoring". There are a million other different reasons why the user decided to answer the question. As long as the answer is *good* and promotes equally good knowledge as the supposed dupe, there's no harm in doing so either. If the user posts a *bad* answer, that is/should be taken care of by the regular voting system.

Comment: "If someone takes the time to post an actual good answer, being blissfully ignorant about existing dupes for whatever reason, and doesn't get the promised reward, that's punishment IMO" - the user can just post his answer on the duplicate instead, as long as there isn't already a better answer with the exactly same solution (in which case it would be useless to have a second, worse copy of it posted as an answer to the duplicate anyways).

Comment: It basically appears to me that we can start talking about shutting SO down, if you rigorously do not accept *any* form of duplication. Anecdotally I'd say 90% of questions are some variation of a dupe. Closing-as-dupe is a great tool; I think you're starting to see it as a goal in itself. Gamefication...?

Comment: @deceze, duplication is fine to an extent. The point here is rather that high-rep users, who should know better, are giving the wrong signal by answering obvious duplicates. How many answers to Javascript closure scope issues in loops do we need? Because I could answer at least one per day if I were so inclined.

Comment: @Frédéric Please note that I don't disagree on that. Yes, dupes should be closed as dupes, no question. What I disagree on is that all dupe answers are bad and users must be punished/not rewarded for posting them. Answers should be judged on their own merit. If the answer is wrong or misleading or not extensive enough, then don't upvote or even downvote it. However, having the same *good* knowledge duplicated, perhaps explained in a few different ways from a few different angles by a number of different people, actually *adds* value IMO.

Comment: @Frédéric ... Because canonical answers tend to be long and detailed and probably overly complex. If there was only one canonical answer, it may not be the most understandable to everyone. Expressing the same thing in different terms a couple of times is to no one's detriment. As long as each one of these explanations is *good*, which should be judged individually. I know this gets *annoying* to frequent users, but what are you going to do about it? Your annoyance should not punish honest contributors (as long *as* they're honest).

Comment: @deceze, that's true, but in that case I believe the canonical post should be fixed (possibly by simply posting the complementary answer under the canonical instead of the duplicate).

Comment: @Frédéric That's hard to implement in practice. Who will decide which answer to move over? Should users keep monitoring all the questions they answered for close votes and retroactively move over their answer? "Nobody" reads more than the first answer anyway, what good is it to have the same answer further down in the same thread? Dupe-answers in the same question are regularly getting downvoted too, because they're seen as plagiarism. You can't really win in this. At least I don't see a clear answer.

Comment: I'm somehow reminded of a (now-suspended) user who copied one of my answers "verbatim" as an answer.  When I asked the user why not mark it as duplicate instead, I was told: "The answer was so good that I felt like spreading it.".  It was perhaps flattering but not amusing.  I downvoted and a couple of others followed suit.

Comment: IIRC, the user in question was a _not-so-low rep_ user (upwards of 20K, if not much more).

Comment: @devnull Might be a cultural issue as well? Most of us here have a firm understanding of "intellectual property", and coupled with SO's idea of "canonical answers" this informs a very specific behaviour. That user OTOH may be from a culture where such things are mostly irrelevant and he really was really into helping the OP who needed help.

Comment: @devnull *"Don't attribute to maliciousness what can adequately be explained by <strike>stupidity</strike> a desire to contribute."* ;)

Comment: @deceze _"Don't attribute everything to a fscking desire to contribute."_  The desire to contribute vanishes into infinity upon receiving a couple of downvotes and the contribution ceases to exist.

Comment: @devnull *"Innocent until proven guilty."*...?

Comment: @devnull *My* enthusiasm would surely also take a big hit if I was downvoted and called names in response to me taking the time to write up what I perceived as a helpful answer.

Comment: @deceze My sympathies with you.  Be "helpful".  Good luck.

Comment: @devnull If that's the sentiment, I say again we can start talking about closing down and freezing SO's state as is. Congratulations all hi-rep users who joined years ago, new users practically lack any chance of ever progressing to where you are now because we've pretty much seen it all by now. The final boss has been slain, the credits screen starts to roll in a minute.

Comment: @deceze To hell with it.  I've stopped answering on SO and intend to maintain the status.  I appreciate your "sentiments" and "enthusiasm" for _educating_ mankind at large.  Best wishes for your efforts!

Comment: @devnull So the only thing we're doing now is to beat up the new arrivals to preserve the status quo, because everything else is pointless? Fantastic...

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure what's the point that you're trying to make.  Go ahead and use sock-puppets to post FAQs and answer those.  It seems that it'll give you a much needed kick.  Ping me if you feel the need for upvotes.

Comment: @devnull Why are we all here if not to educate in the first place? If there's no joy in it for you, maybe you shouldn't be here. If the only people hanging 'round SO are people whose joy it is to think about how best to punish users for the sake of the system, it's not a place I want to be.

Comment: @deceze Same questions and answers don't amuse me.  YMMV.  Enough of it now; this thread is already getting too long.  I'm reminded of something: _Never try to teach a pig to sing.  It annoys the pig and wastes your time._

Comment: @devnull They're not amusing me either. But I'm trying to remember *why* they annoy me exactly and whether it's really something that I *can* and *should* get my panties in a bunch about. ;)

Comment: Regarding your last edit (regarding regulars who get tired of seeing the same stuff), perhaps those regulars should slow down on SO and try to have a healthier life balance. (I'm talking as someone who has a unhealthy consecutive day count, well past the gold badge ;-) )

Comment: @Bruno Absolutely. I'm in the same camp. And I've realised that getting annoyed on SO is pretty pointless, because SO isn't going to change.

Comment: @deceze So you say SO has finally failed its ambitious goals? I always said you cannot have quantity AND quality here at the same time. Do you say we should give up quality then, just to "help" people (this is obviously not real help)? Or should we close down the whole thing? Or leave it and let it be the playground of the unwashed masses, and maybe start over again somewhere else? And be more careful about trying to become "popular" again?

Comment: @kapa, SO has always been build around a Q&A mechanism, encouraged by a simple gaming process. It's not Wikipedia, there's nothing in place to consolidate knowledge together. Editing a bunch of answers all together, to whatever canonical question we make up, has serious problems regarding crediting authorship, from a gamification point of view, ethically, and almost certainly legally (having our answers merged together isn't what we signed up for, even if you fall back on the CC licence, correct means of attribution will be a nightmare).

Comment: @kapa It think SO has greatly *succeeded* in its goals, to the point that it's mostly saturated. I think it's worth considering that SO is entering a second phase in its life, or perhaps an "endgame" if you will. The system served us well to build up an incredible library of knowledge which is helping millions of programmers. However, because it has build up this knowledge, the system used to build is not suited as a means to maintain it as well. I agree that we've probably reached a tipping point in which it is detrimental to quality now.

Comment: @kapa ... The question is, are we seeing SO as a treasure to conserve and can SO make the transition to this state without dying off; or will we continue with the interactive Q&A but make the necessary changes in both philosophy and system to make it work under these saturated circumstances.

Comment: @deceze I agree. The quality is just decreasing, and I feel it is becoming harder for me to find valuable, useful information when I'm searching here (which would be the main goal, as I perceive). Owners should give up one of the conflicting goals (I'd give up quantity, even close down the site for a few months and clean it up). If not, we fail both goals, in fact we are already failing them. I personally do not want SO to become one of those useless, unsearchable, low quality forums, we have enough of those.

Comment: @Bruno Wasn't/isn't creating a library of knowledge the main goal? If not, I've been fooled and probably wasting my time here :). I'm not really interested in some social chit-chat where some people pretend they are learning and others pretend they are so nice and helping others so much... that's useless.

Comment: "innocent until proven guilty" on SO is more like "noob until proven able to google and read the docs". And your point about being "saturated" is just plain nonsense; there are always new technologies and thousands of questions for old tech that have not been asked yet. We're just saturated with the same old noob questions from people who are either unable or unwilling to search and read documentation - which is a vicious circle as it causes the harder or more involved questions to drown in a sea of easily-answered almost-duplicates.

Comment: @l4mpi Sure, noobs not searching for existing content and/or not understanding it *is* a problem. But again, this is not going away, unless something changes drastically. FWIW, I've mostly been fighting against the tide as of late instead of answering questions, which IMO is unproductive. We should think about how to integrate all those noob dupes into the system instead of fighting against them. Because they're not going away and they can't be punished away. "Use your opponent's force against themselves" kinda thing. :)

Comment: @kapa, it may have been the intended goal, but it sounds more like a lovely motto than anything else. How to create that library of knowledge is what makes SO what it is (not so much what it's trying to be), and as I said, the life blood of SO has always been its questions and answers (including the fact there were people willing to answer of course). The exact way that knowledge is built is precisely by having people trying to learn and people willing to help, fortunately or unfortunately.

Comment: @l4mpi The real advantage of "noob dupes" is that they serve as yet another entry point to the same knowledge. There are a million different ways how someone may search for a problem; having more dupes point to the same source is only beneficial in this regard. Currently closing as dupe is a very thankless job; and introducing new punishments for not doing it isn't going to do any good IMO. Work *with* it, not against it.

Comment: @kapa [... cont'd ... ] What makes SO's strength also makes its weakness. The fact that a Q&A is a self-contained entity is its strength compared to forums: you ask a question, and you're meant to answer it without digressing too much or going into a debate. Unfortunately, this self-containment is also the weakness of the model, since there's not much to consolidate similar knowledge together. By doing so (especially on complex questions), you could break this cohesion between a question and its answers.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, fortunately we had and surely still have people who are interested in learning and helping, in the real sense (not just solving their current problems/polishing their egos). That is why we have useful content, unfortunately hidden in the dust most of the time.

Comment: @deceze The "noob dupes" is only helpful to a certain point and actively harmful after this - when it starts saturating the search results of other, unrelated issues. And re "not going away": I'm starting to think a "free to read, paid to contribute" site would be the best solution. Just charge everyone $5 once to sign up and get ask/answer privileges, then permaban people who are unable to read the site rules or can't provide useful contributions. This would ensure that people think harder about signing up and have a harder time coming back from a ban.

Comment: @l4mpi That would be one possible solution, yes. But it would very drastically change the nature of SO. Maybe too drastically. "The Hyphen Site" died once SO came along, because it was pay-walled, and SO wasn't...

Comment: @l4mpi And FWIW, I'm typically able to find what I'm looking for through Google. I agree that SO's search largely sucks, that's no secret. Maybe that point of complaint would go away with a better search engine?

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, unfortunately this community-driven, free way of doing this is doomed to fail (not in the financial sense), as it seems. I don't like this, because I believed in it, but starting to accept it.

Comment: @deceze I've had these problems with google searches as well. And regarding the unfortunately-named, not-really-about-transgender-issues site, it was doomed to fail because reading the content was blocked - this is why I said "free to read". If they had not hidden their answers behind a pay/login-wall, maybe SO would never exist in the first place.

Comment: @l4mpi Fair enough. As long as 20k+ users get free-for-life access, I'm for this proposal then. ;)