# How to encourage flagging as duplicate instead of answering unoriginal questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, reputation

I know the subject of **receiving reputation for flags** has been discussed before but I feel that it wasn't discussed enough. So here are my thoughts:

1. I am not an experienced programmer, sometimes I know the answer because I encountered the problem myself others I just search for answers out of curiosity. In many cases the problem was already asked on this site and have a good accepted answer so I flagged the question.
2. I think all of us have search for answers and found them on other sites or documentations at least once. What is the difference between taking the answer from there and posting it to the question and flagging, which is giving to the user a link to an answer on the same website.
3. When previously asked the question about reputation for flags the answer was that *the users should flag questions out of the desire to keep this site clean*. I am sorry but the users (most of them) want reputation.
4. I do not ask that the flags should be rewarded, I am just pointing out the obvious, most of users post answers weather the question was asked before or not.

**After readying other related questions and the comments:**

1. Don't you show effort when you search for an answer or analyze the question to see if it is appropriate for this site?
2. Should't a user who knew the answer or found it but choose to flag the question be more rewarded than one who just threw an answer without checking?
3. And for the case when new answers are given to duplicated question, wouldn't be better if the one who asks mentions that he already searched and found the question but is not satisfied with the answer?

As a conclusion, and since the question was flagged as duplicate although I don't find the other answers satisfying:

- It appears it's better to **answer the question than to flag it as duplicate**, maybe your answer will bring something new (rarely does)
- If you find that the question was already asked **post the response from where you find it**, by the time the question will be marked as duplicate or put on hold the user might have accepted the answer or your answer would have received up-votes. *It's the same as if you found the answer on other sites or knew it.*
- If the one who asks didn't bother searching before, **why should you?**. Post the answer, he accepts it, he is happy, you got rep, you are happy.

**From the perspective of a new user everything looks so nice on this site, but after you spend some time on it and see how hungry for rep some users are...**

Comment: In point 1, why did you flag a question at all? What did you flag it *for*, what problem needed fixing?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5

Comment: I completely agree.  Why should we give reputation, thus privileges, to rep hunters instead of people keeping the site clean?  Don't we want these people to have more moderation privileges?

Comment: And so far we have been doing **fine** with handling bad content through flagging without rewarding reputation. Why do you feel that giving reputation for flags is a good idea? That would give the *entirely wrong incentive*; people will *overflag* to try and get more reputation.

Comment: @Martijn read the questions I linked. A _lot_ of (high-rep) users prefer to answer (often by _copying existing answers_) instead of trying to find a duplicate. Answering is rewarded, flagging is not. That being said, ironically, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters People can only flag so much in one day. Plus, it would still be much easier to get reputation from answers rather than flags. Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand how rep hunting instead of flagging, closing, and deleting should get users more moderation privileges.

Comment: @Anonymous totally agree. Especially with all the talk on Meta about "rep's not a measure of skill it's a measure of your involvement with the SO community" etc, you'd think it'd be more encouraged to be a productive member of the community rather than a rep hunter who answers duplicates, but that's not the case at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters also... people are already *overanswering* in search of rep. People give bad 30-second answers to duplicate questions and get points for it. How is it better to encourage this behavior than to encourage good moderation when deciding who to give moderation privileges to?

Comment: Hear hear, Yay to this here proposal. As SO is growing, I think it's not unreasonable to change expectations and priorities. Honestly, these days I'm close-Mjölniring questions left and right, it's almost a full time job. Much more so than even a year ago. If we're rewarding tiny question edits with a little bit of reputation, why not closing as duplicates too? Both actions are for increasing the quality of the site, and IMO deserve a reward. Accountability can arguably be tough with this one, but it's solvable. I wouldn't even mind excluding Mjölnir from this reward scheme.

Comment: Does nobody here but @CodeCaster see the meta-ness of this question?

Comment: Can you make the duplicate search suck less?  Because if so, fewer duplicates will get asked and more people will close questions as duplicates.

Comment: There is always the possibility that a version of the software released since the original question was asked provides a different, more efficient solution to whatever the problem is than the original accepted answer.

Comment: @barrick those are edge cases, most duplicates are lack of research. tmyklebu you don't search from the duplicate popup, you search the web using "site:stackoverflow.com". Jashaszun thanks, but - what? Anyway, voted to reopen, this specific question is not asked nor answered in the duplicate. Altough the highests voted answer vouches for "propose we reward duplicate-finders", that has not been responded to.

Comment: @Jashaszun: It doesn't just have meta-ness. It's self-referential ever since it was flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: As someone who uses Mjölnir to close `bash` duplicates, I'm fine with excluding said use from reputation rewards. How might we handle the issue, if any, of lower-rep users who feel "cheated" out of a reward because a question was Mjölnired before they had a chance to cast a close vote?

Comment: An observation:  The list of potential dupes that appears while one is entering the question is usually far better than the "Related" list that appears in the margin or the list that appears when you go to flag a dupe.  Make it easier to access that first list so that dupes can be more easily flagged.  As it is, I often have to start a question and type in the title to find a good dupe, when I know one is there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two important reasons we close duplicates:

1. Have one canonical version. Concentrate effort on that one.
2. Not turn off our top users. Constantly seeing the same question again is annoying. It also shows a lack of research skills which can be painful to witness.

We want the deduplication process to function as effectively as possible.

Why do users suggest duplicates? Personally, I do it when I'm appalled by the question. There isn't any other reward than to see the question die. Maybe some people just like tidying up the site?! Should this be the only reward?

People don't do *anything* without a reward. There must be *some* reward.

Giving reputation for helpful actions works. We know that. So let's give some to closing users (under certain conditions). The linked questions ([Rewarding overzealous users for answering duplicate questions is undermining the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the), [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5)) have reasonable discussion about how that could look like. That's just a detail. The team will figure it out.

Comment: The thing is, if flags get rewarded the admins will have a hole lot of work to do.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu I never would reward flags (because you're right about that). I'd reward close votes.

Comment: I'd made rep private. Personally I don't even understand why are they struggling so much for it, but maybe it's just for showoff.

Comment: *"Maybe some people just like tidying up the site?!"* - that's why I do it. Watching a bad question die is just frosting on the cake. It also has the benefit of concentrating on the canonical answer.

Comment: I think we also need to do some work to make the canonical answers more general. I know that just the other day I saw a question about Java Swing where someone was blocking the UI thread and needed to use a SwingWorker. I know I've seen variations on this in the past, but when I did a search I couldn't find a good question to mark it as a duplicate of that wasn't polluted with tons of highly localized, irrelevant details.

Comment: @DavidConrad you are right, it happens that I was also looking for a good general example of a SwingWorker but all the answers were to particular and I asked a new question for my case.

Comment: @DavidConrad: something to induce rework/generalization/reorganization/cleaning/canonification of important answers? that would be nice. how to do that? through editorial choice of questions with call to high reps to wikify it, similarly to what is done on wikipedia? Have there been discussion regarding that?

Comment: @njzk2 There haven't been discussions to my knowledge. I don't know what the best way to go about doing that would be, but I think it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the reward part, I think we should base it off individual user's experience on this site. Could be total reputation, or number of questions previously closed as duplicate and not reopened within 30 days after that. Reward should be given to the first person who suggested a duplicate (therefore encouraging users to compete for flagging as a duplicate).

If based on total reputation, could be 3 tiers:

- 1 reputation, if user is below 10K.
- 5 reputation, if user is above 10K, but below 100K.
- 10 reputation, if user is above 100K.
- 20 reputation, if you are [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). :) I was going to write "above 1M", but figured we don't have any user in this reputation bracket yet.

Based on number of "helpful" duplicate flags:

- 1 reputation each, until 10 helpful duplicate flags reached.
- 2 reputation each, between 10 and 50.
- 5 reputation each, between 50 and 100.
- 10 reputation each, after 100.

For a helpful flag to count, a grace period of 30 days must be honored, which kicks in immediately after question is closed. This should prevent rep scam.

Numbers are not set in stone, but are not random either. I feel they represent a goal each user tier would be willing to pursue. Giving 100K user 1 reputation point as a reward sounds mean to me. On the other hand, giving 10 points to a new user is too much. For me personally (10K range -> +5 for a duplicate flag), this change would hardly affect anything - I am rarely the first one to find a duplicate anyway.

Comment: With or without reputation for flagging the site took a bad turn, users ask poor and duplicate questions because other users are competing to answer and get rep.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu: If we start rewarding users who currently "Don't care", there is a high chance questions will be closed before an answer is given, resulting in little to no reputation gain for the potential answerer.