# Submit Answer after the question was close

Tags: bug

I was answering a question,in the same time the question was closed.

The submit button was disable, I removed the disable tag from button and my answer was submitted.

I thing this is bug.

I think they aren't  check it in server side code :-)

Comment: Wow, you *really* wanted to answer that question! :-)

Comment: See [This answer was posted \*after\* the question was closed, how is that possible?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible)