# "Add Another Answer" button not available

Tags: support

I cannot figure out why I cannot add an answer to a Stack Overflow question.

Does it have something to do with reputation?

Here is the post in question: [Div does not wrap around form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084119/div-does-not-wrap-around-form)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with reputation. The question is closed, which means no new answers can be posted to it.*

See the yellow banners above and below the question? These banners, to be specific:

[image]

Those banners appear whenever a question has been closed.

In this case, the question has been marked as a "duplicate," meaning it's been asked (and answered) before. If the question had been closed for any other reason, the top of the two banners would not appear.

If you're positive you can add something that *hasn't been covered in other answers* on the question linked in the top banner, you can add an answer there.

For more about question closure, see [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on-hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) in the help center.

As a side note, the "Add Another Answer" button only appears if *you* have already posted an answer. If the question is open and only other users have answered it, you'll see the answer field at the bottom of the page instead.

---

<sub>* You may notice that the answer on that question was posted after the question was closed. That user likely started writing before the question was closed and posted in the answer grace period. See [This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible) for more on that.</sub>

Comment: Perfect answer.  Thanks for taking the time!