# How long is the "grace" period for answering closed questions, and why is it only applicable to some?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

I know that there is (somewhere) a question that asks about how answers can be posted on a closed question, and it's due to a "grace" period. I would link it, but my Google-fu is failing me right now, so someone who doesn't fail please do edit it in.

My question, however, is how long is that "grace" period, and why does it only apply to some? I ask this as I, personally, have *never* been able to answer a closed question; I have never "benefited" from the "grace" period. Others, however, seem to be able to answer questions some time after the question is closed. For example, in this question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64571835/timeline) you can see that user *GMB* is afforded almost 10 minutes (9 minutes 40 seconds) to answer it. *(I want to clarify that I am not promoting users to vote on this question or related answers, which often happens when you link them on meta. This is just an example.)*

I don't mind the grace period, though I personally think that if it does exist it should be consistent. There have been several times where I will be answering a question, and then I go to submit the answer and because I did so seconds (literally seconds) after the close vote completed my answer was rejected. Some of those answers I have put (significant) time into, and thus I then have to save off the Markdown content, vote to reopen, and then bookmark the question so that I can get the opportunity to answer. I'm pretty confident there's then been at least one example where someone else has posted an answer after I have previously been refused the "right".

If there is a grace period, then why does it only "benefit" some and not others? Why is it not even consistent for all users on a specific question? From a user experience perspective that isn't particularly "fair" (especially when you put effort into answering) and feels like the behaviour is more a "bug" (feature?) than by design.

---

[Follow on question on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357558/397219)

Comment: *"About 4 hours"* - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one

Comment: That answer, however, states *"We don't block answers that are "in flight" at the time of close, the window for answering -- assuming you've started composing an answer before the question is closed -- is about 4 hours."*, and I can assure you that is **not** true from my experience, @Nick . I make that very much clear in my question That answer is, however, 9 years old, so I wouldn't be surprised that the the statement is no longer applicable.

Comment: Related: [This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252711/11682469) (includes links to relevant MSE posts)

Comment: @Larnu It also states that they disable the "Post your answer" checkbox, you have to manually re-enable that, it's not at all clear in your question what you mean by only some benefiting from it, this applies to _all_ questions

Comment: I think that the official answer is "a few hours, if the client-side validation fails". This came up a few times, and the answer is always more or less the same. I imagine the vagueness is intentional.

Comment: *"it's not at all clear in your question what you mean by only some benefiting from it"* because I have never "benefited" from being able to answer a closed question (and by that I mean, I was writing the answer before it was closed), even by mere seconds, @Nick, where as I have seen others do so multiple times. It's not that specific questions benefit, but that some users do. If there is a grace period for those already answering a question then that grace period should be applicable to all users, not just some because *unknown reason here*.

Comment: The unknown reason is "client side validation fails". I.e. they managed (intentional or because of a JS error) to click the "post answer" button **after** the question was closed, and **before** _"a few hours"_ had passed.

Comment: Which leads me to the latter point the closing point of *"From a UX perspectively that isn't particularly "fair" (especially when you put effort into answering) and feels like the behaviour is more a "bug" (feature?) than by design."* @yivi .

Comment: I am the author of the said answer. For what it's worth: (1) I did not get the notification banner that the question had been closed. (2) I did not start composing the answer before it was closed; I usually type my answer in a text editor before copy/pasting it to the site, which is what I did here. I agree with @Larnu that it would be great if the rules could be "officially" clarified, so everyone can better understand the process.

Comment: @Nick That answer is 9 years old and most certainly not applicable today. The rules have changed and OP's situation can easily be experienced; I've experienced it too.

Comment: @Sinatr from the question *"There have been several times where I will be answering a question, and then I go to submit the answer and because I did so seconds (literally seconds) after the close vote completed my answer is rejected."* I'm not so keyboard proficient I can write an entire answer in a couple of seconds. ;)

Comment: @Larnu I'm sure that's not true! :)

Comment: I'm not Gordon, (who I'm sure has a directory of copy and paste answers at their disposal) @CaiusJard. it takes me *at least* 1 minute to write some of my answers. ;)

Comment: You shouldn't generally be answering questions that are getting closed.

Comment: @philipxy just because a question has been closed doesn't been it should have. I elaborate that in the question: *"thus I then have to save off the markdown, **vote to reopen**, and then bookmark the question"* 3 VTCs doesn't take long in popular tags, and pile on votes do happen, even if people don't believe it.

Comment: Also people answer & vote to reopen questions that should be closed. Anyway my last comment said "generally".

Comment: Yes, but my point is, @philipxy, is that if I'm answering a question I don't feel it should be closed; I'm pretty prolific with my close votes in the tags I am active with as quality, vagueness, and duplicates are common. Notice in the example I give, *I* am the one that closed it (with a gold badge); I never intended to answer it.

Comment: @philipxy: All too many get closed because 5 people couldn't be bothered to read it carefully.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Three people now. Disastrous change.

Comment: @StackOverthrow: I never was good at counting...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The grace period is [4 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38228/incorrectly-able-to-answer-a-closed-question#comment187404_44634), where the only thing stopping you is JavaScript on the client side. (After that, the server will not let you post an answer.) You just need to get around that client side validation, which can be done any number of ways on purpose, such as:

- Start writing an answer (or at least load the page) before the question is closed and when the submit button is disabled look at the HTML source and re-enable it.
- Start writing an answer on a different (open) question and change where the form is submitted to (the closed question), then submit.
- Press the button to start an answer on the app before it’s closed and submit it like normal. (You may not even realize the question is closed until after you post so this occasionally happens by accident.)

The idea was to make sure that people aren’t punished for a technical problem where [the page doesn’t show that the question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210295/submitting-an-answer-to-a-closed-question#comment674340_210295) before they submit. It’s hard to say what could cause a problem like that (other than NoScript, if you can even use the site like that), as it might have something to do with either the browser or the internet connection.

As the comments say, this isn’t there so that people can answer off topic questions or circumvent getting 2-3 reopen votes. If you’re seen exploiting this, you could be suspended.

(Also, you can’t use this to post an answer to a migration stub. And there’s not really a reason anyone would want to: Just go to the open question on the new site to post your answer.)

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Intentional circumvention of system imposed limitations, including the limitation on not posting answers to closed questions, is considered abuse of the system and is grounds for warnings and suspensions.

Comment: I suppose the question now is, "should question is 'flight' be allowed to be posted again, when only some can benefit from the grace period." Seems more like this is a "feature" really that some are "allowed" to post while others not.

Comment: @Larnu what do you mean by "Should question is 'flight'(..)"?

Comment: A phrase from [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79457/397219) by Jeff from 9~ years ago. Though I should have said "answer"; apologies the coffee hadn't kicked in yet. :)

Comment: The most likely way that error can arise is a race condition between whatever mechanism lets the client-side know to disable the post-button and the user clicking the post-button.

Comment: Click answer, post nonsensical answer, delete it. Edit deleted state, undelete might also be a way to get "new" answers into closed ones  - but above 10k or by inspecting the timeline you could see this was done.

Comment: @PatrickArtner That is frowned upon and I've been told that is also grounds for moderator warnings. "by inspecting the timeline you could see this was done". I do not think so. The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64572026/timeline) does not show to have been deleted at any point. Unless you mean there is yet another Answer on this Question that has never been un-deleted.

Comment: Seems to me this is a pretty poor design. Especially now that the site continuously saves your work (so it's easy to detect that an answer is being edited), the policy should be changed: if you start writing an answer before a question is closed, and continue working on it through its closure, and post afterwards (for up to 4 hours) it should simply be accepted and posted. It's frustrating as hell to work for an hour on writing an answer, and then have it thrown away because 5 other people didn't understand the question.

Comment: @PatrickArtner To be clear: We consider posting a placeholder "answer" to also be intentional circumvention of system imposed limitations, which would receive a similar response. However, it is *also* generally deceptive in that it provides your answer with an earlier date/time for when it was originally posted than when your actual answer was posted. So, just doing that is inappropriate, even if it doesn't result in, or isn't intended to result in, being able to post an answer on a closed question.

Comment: I do agree on that, @JerryCoffin. I suspect, however, that the asking for it to be changed, or asking if the intention is correct, is a question for [se]. I'll probably ask something over there tomorrow.

Comment: @Larnu: Clearly belongs a meta site.Might be room for argument about which one, but I'd say the basic idea applies across the network, not just on SO proper.

Comment: We all know that frontend-only validation shouldn't be trusted. Locks only keep honest people honest. Beyond the cases this feature was meant to solve, it seems like we're leaving it wide open for anyone willing to spend 30 seconds to abuse it.

Comment: I don't get it. If the idea is that if someone has gone to the trouble of writing an answer then it shouldn't go to waste, then why disable the post button immediately (instead of four hours later)? Or if we think that closed questions shouldn't get new answers, why not reject answers that were in flight? Why are they more deserving, just because they somehow missed (avoided) the client-side check?